# Extracting path element to make a string in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to synthesize a string from a directory name in bash. I need to extract the last two path names to make a string.

For example, with an input `/a/b/c`, I want to make "b_c_HELLO".

How can I do that with bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `basename` and `dirname`:

```
parent=$(dirname "$input")
output=$(basename "$parent")_$(basename "$input")_HELLO
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $PATH|awk -F"/" '{print $(NF-1)"_"$NF"_HELLO";}'
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure bash implementation leveraging [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073):

```
input="a/b/c"
tmp="${input%%/*/*}"
tmp="${tmp#$tmp/}"
output="${tmp/\//_}_HELLO"
```

Also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100